# How to stop airconsole client app from auto rotating

Tags: unity-game-engine, orientation, fixed, airconsole

I've got a control scheme that makes use a mobile device's orientation data - roll and pitch.

But when rotating the mobile device, the airconsole client app auto rotates too, breaking the control scheme - as one rotates along the X axis (in landscape orientation).

I've looked through the API and can't seem to find any setting that indicates setting orientation to fixed.

I'd very much prefer to not have to create an html/css hack that rotates my controller within the client app.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about disabling the rotation of the game from profile view to landscape view, you can find that under Edit -> Project Settings -> Player and will open the player settings on the inspector in Unity. Select the target platform from the list. Click the Resolution and Presentation section. Change it from auto-rotation to whatever you prefer, landscape left/right or profile view.